# My ~/.Xresources is disabling gtk antialiasing

Tags: x11, fonts, gtk, x-resources

When booting into my window manage (xmonad), gtk fonts are anti-aliased, but for some reason urxvt has problems with variable names in my `~/.Xdefaults` (it fails to parse the variable names as colors and thus everything is pink). This is fixed by running `xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults`. However, doing this seems to disable anti-aliasing for fonts in gtk apps, but not in urxvt.

What would be causing this?

I've since moved my `~/.Xdefaults` to `~/.Xresources`, and now, gtk antialiasing seems to not be working from the get-go, but I still need to run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` to get urxvt to parse the color variables.

My `~/.Xresources`:

```
Xft.dpi: 96
Xft.lcdfiler: lcddefault
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintfull

URxvt.font: xft:Dejavu Sans Mono:size=11:antialias=true:hinting=true

URxvt*scrollBar: true
URxvt*scrollBar_right: true
URxvt*scrollstyle: plain

URxvt.urgentOnBell: true

! From https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164108
URxvt.intensityStyles: false

! From https://raw.github.com/solarized/xresources/master/solarized
! Solarized color scheme for the X Window System
!
! http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized


! Common

#define S_yellow        #b58900
#define S_orange        #cb4b16
#define S_red           #dc322f
#define S_magenta       #d33682
#define S_violet        #6c71c4
#define S_blue          #268bd2
#define S_cyan          #2aa198
#define S_green         #859900


! Dark

#define S_base03        #002b36
#define S_base02        #073642
#define S_base01        #586e75
#define S_base00        #657b83
#define S_base0         #839496
#define S_base1         #93a1a1
#define S_base2         #eee8d5
#define S_base3         #fdf6e3


! Light

! #define S_base03        #fdf6e3
! #define S_base02        #eee8d5
! #define S_base01        #93a1a1
! #define S_base00        #839496
! #define S_base0         #657b83
! #define S_base1         #586e75
! #define S_base2         #073642
! #define S_base3         #002b36


! To only apply colors to your terminal, for example, prefix
! the color assignment statement with its name. Example:
!
! URxvt*background:            S_base03

*background:              S_base03
*foreground:              S_base0
*fading:                  40
*fadeColor:               S_base03
*cursorColor:             S_base1
*pointerColorBackground:  S_base01
*pointerColorForeground:  S_base1

*color0:                  S_base02
*color1:                  S_red
*color2:                  S_green
*color3:                  S_yellow
*color4:                  S_blue
*color5:                  S_magenta
*color6:                  S_cyan
*color7:                  S_base2
*color8:                  S_base03
*color9:                  S_orange
*color10:                 S_base01
*color11:                 S_base00
*color12:                 S_base0
*color13:                 S_violet
*color14:                 S_base1
*color15:                 S_base3
```

Answer (score 3):

Many X programs (including Urxvt) that use resources load `~/.Xdefaults` when they start and apply the resources they find there. When they do that, they don't apply any preprocessing, so your `#define` directives have no effect, which explains the messages like

```
urxvt: unable to parse color 'S_base0', using pink instead.
```

The Xrdb program loads a resource file into the server and these resources apply to all applications that are started subsequently. Xrdb preprocesses the input file with the C preprocessor `cpp` (unless instructed otherwise).

If some resources seemingly change when you switch from `.Xdefaults` loaded by applications to `.Xresources` loaded at the beginning of the session, this may be due to some other part of your configuration (perhaps a system-wide one) loading something else afterwards. If loading `.Xresources` manually after the session starts makes a difference, that's what's going on; you'll need to check your session and window manager startup routines. Check what the actual resources are with `xrdb -query | grep '^Xft'` and with `listres Xft`.

Most Gtk applications ignore X resources, you need to use [fontconfig settings](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_Configuration#Fontconfig_configuration) instead.